# Android BLE getServices() not work

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've made a android ble application which can connect to ble devices and get service/characteristic list of the devices.

It has worked well as i expected for "galaxy note 4 (android 6.0 , BLE: 4.1, A2DP, EDR, LE)" and "galaxy S4 (android 5.0, BLE 4.0, A2DP, EDR, LE, aptX)" for almost ble devices which support ble 4.0.

However, I can not get service/characteristic list of some ble devices using the same application on "galaxy s4". On "galaxy note 4", It works well.

Why i can not get service/characteristic list using "galaxy s4" using same app and same ble devices (which work well on "galaxy note 4" with same app)???

As i know, ble 4.0 and 4.1 are compatible. Also my application supports over android 5.0 lollipop version.

Are there devices which prohibit connection and readCharacteristic process according to android version or BLE 4.X version??

Thanks for reading

===============================

- Update 17/04/25

Below is the "nrf_connection" image on "galaxy s4"
Only default services like 0x1800, 0x1801, 0x180a show on galaxy s4.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4i3X.jpg)

- Update 17/04/26\

Thanks for all comments. I tried BLE scanning for other "galaxy s4". It worked well. I think the first "galaxy s4" is not normal.

Comment: the problem you're facing is only from the client side? the bluetooth device that act as server is always the same?

Comment: What error do you get? Status codes? Have you performed a service discovery? Please add the relevant code. Have you tried to connect with a 3rd party app, like "nrf connect"?

Comment: @lelloman  Thanks for reading. I'm not sure of the ble chipset version of the devices, but the interfaces are always same from the cliedt side.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for reading. 
Sorry for the loss of images. 
Yes. I test using "nrf connect" and the phenomena was same.
Only default services like 0x1800, 0x1801, 0x180a show on galaxy s4.

Comment: Hmm, sounds weird. Have you tried to clear the Bluetooth cache on the S4? Maybe the service discovery was failing once and the cached state is not valid? -> http://www.smartmobilephonesolutions.com/content/how-to-fix-bluetooth-android-cell-phone

Comment: @Christopher Thanks. I check the clearing the cache as the link but same thing happened

Comment: I asked because I tried to use an S4 neo as bluetooth le gatt server but apparently it just can't do it for hardware limitations. it worked as a client though